# Excessively Large Bundle Size and Source Map for React Project

Tags: reactjs, build, react-dom, webpack-production

I'm experiencing a significant issue with the build size of my React project. The size of the `static/js/main.93955c9e.js.map` file in my project is close to 32 MB. This is significantly larger than expected, and I'm looking for ways to optimize it.

Project Details:

- React version: 18.2.0
- Dependencies & devDependencies from package.json:

```
{
 "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-drag-drop-files": "^2.3.10",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
 }
 "devDependencies": {
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.3"
 }
}
```

The build size of my React project has become much larger than anticipated, with the `main.93955c9e.js.map` file reaching close to 32 MB. I've analyzed the bundle and source map using `source-map-explorer`, and I have a list of the 10 largest files/modules contributing to the size. Here is the list for reference:

- `react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js` (Size: 12 MB)
- `components/ComposeDraft.jsx` (Size: 13.6 KB)
- `pages/email/Page.jsx` (Size: 13.1 KB)
- `@emotion/stylis/dist/stylis.browser.esm.js` (Size: 8.2 KB)
- `react-drag-drop-files/dist/react-drag-drop-files.esm.js` (Size: 7.8 KB)
- `@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/regeneratorRuntime.js` (Size: 6.6 KB)
- `react/cjs/react.production.min.js` (Size: 6.4 KB)
- `pages/projectMaster/Page.jsx` (Size: 6.4 KB)
- `@remix-run/router/utils.ts` (Size: 6.3 KB)
- `react-router/lib/hooks.tsx` (Size: 5.9 KB)

I'm looking for guidance on how to reduce the bundle size and source map size. Are there any specific optimizations or configurations that can help minimize these files? Additionally, if anyone has insights into why `react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js` is particularly large, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Any suggestions, tips, or guidance on optimizing my React project's build size and addressing this issue would be highly valuable. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You might want to read up on [code splitting](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) as a way to reduce the initial load and fetch bundles when they are needed. It's not really about making things smaller, you potentially need all that code and bits over the wire, but rather breaking it all up into smaller parts for consumption.